# Interchange Argmin and Monotone Function

Tags: optimization, monotone-functions, set-valued-analysis

Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is lower semi-continuous, and coercive (so it admits a minimizer) and suppose that $g:(0,\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is monotone increasing and smooth.  Then is it true that
$$
\operatorname{argmin}_{x \in X} f(x) = \operatorname{argmin}_{x \in X}g \circ f(x)?
$$

Comment: maybe im missing something, but doesn't $g(x)=x+1 $ is a counter example? (take $f=1$ )

Comment: No, in both those cases $X=argmin_{x \in X} 1 = argmin_{x \in X} f(x) \& argmin_{x \in X} g\circ f(x) = argmin_{x \in X} 2=X$.  (It's not true for $\inf$ but I'm considering $\operatorname{arginf}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\implies$ Suppose $x^* \in \underset{x \in X}{\mathrm{arg\min}} \: f(x)$. Then $f(x^*) \leq f(x)$, $\forall x \in X$. Since $g$ is monotone increasing, this implies $g(f(x^*)) \leq g(f(x))$, $\forall x \in X$. Therefore $x^* \in \underset{x \in X}{\mathrm{arg\min}} \: g(f(x))$.

$\impliedby$ Suppose $x^* \in \underset{x \in X}{\mathrm{arg\min}} \: g(f(x))$. Then $g(f(x^*)) \leq g(f(x))$, $\forall x \in X$. Since $g$ is monotone increasing, [it has an inverse that is also monotone increasing](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Strictly_Monotone_Function). Taking the inverse on both sides yields $f(x^*) \leq f(x)$, $\forall x \in X$. Therefore, $x^* \in \underset{x \in X}{\mathrm{arg\min}} \: f(x)$.

Comment: Is it necessary that $f$ is lower semi-continuous?

Comment: @Mikal I don't think so - we only require the optimization problems to have minimizers.

Comment: +1 Cool stuff thanks